# "I don't know" is to "agnostic" as "I don't care" is to what adjective?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy, religion

Atheists reject that God exists and agnostics do not know if God exists. What is the word for people who do not care if God exists? Does some word moonlight for that or is there a specific term (apart from the usual adjectives like *indifferent*, etc.)?

Comment: By "don't care" do you mean are indifferent to the possibility that God exists or believe that the existence (or not) of God makes no discernible difference to the world as they know it? I doubt that a single word can cover both possibilities.

Comment: @Fortiter: The first one.

Comment: Here is an article that may be of interest to you: [Atheism = untheism + antitheism](http://lesswrong.com/lw/11m/atheism_untheism_antitheism/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a portmanteau word *apatheism* (combining *apathy* and *theism/atheism*) which may suffice, providing the agent noun ***apatheist***.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apatheism) lists this indifference as *pragmatic atheism, practical atheism* and *apathethic agnosticism,* any of which may be preferable to a portmanteau neologism.

Comment: Upvoted. But I would also point out that I find "apatheist" offers succinctness and fairly decent interpretability.

Comment: And then there's those who are both: [The Church of the Apathetic Agnostic](http://uctaa.net/) Motto: *We don't know, and we don't care.*

Answer (score 5):

I've heard "apatheist" used in this sense.

Answer (score 3):

An additional category that may fit the "I don't care" category—besides the apathetic position that "I am bored by and lack interest in religion"—is the position that "the central subject that religion purports to address (namely, God) is inherently incomprehensible and thus irrelevant to human life." This view has been elaborated under two terms: [*theological noncognitivism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theological_noncognitivism) and [*ignosticism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignosticism). Wikipedia has entries for both terms, as well as for the umbrella term [*nontheism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontheism), which seems to apply to any theory that denies a positive faith in God's existence.

Fundamentally, the theological noncognitivist and the ignostic deny the importance of theological questions; they "don't care" because they have concluded that nothing knowable or meaningful lies at the core of religion to care about.

Comment: With all due respect to you and the Wikipedia authors, *theological noncognitivism* and *ignosticism* are terms that are used by only a few authors, and are unlikely to be understood outside the context of discussing their work. This kind of a position is, in fact, much better known in the version formulated by A. J. Ayer in *Language, Truth and Logic* than in the versions mentioned in the Wikipedia, but Ayer did not give that position any particular label. The position is, incidentally, that religious claims are literally meaningless, not merely unimportant or irrelevant to human life.